# How to fold in text field to above the combo box

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

this code is displaying a combo box for user who wants to make a change to the data. we are 
displaying above this combo box our item substitution suggestion coming from a table.
now they dont want to show this suggestion but just a text message, 'Please note suggestion on main page'.

How and where can i fold in the new text?  if i can, i like to keep 'dead fields '
 because they are always changing.

```
<Styles GroupPanel-ForeColor="Black"></Styles>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>

            <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="popupStatus" ClientInstanceName="popupStatus" runat="server" ShowFooter="false" ShowCloseButton="true" ShowShadow="true" Modal="true" Width="500px" Height="250px"
                PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter" HeaderText="Update Status">
                <ContentCollection>
                    <dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                        <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="cbpStatus" ClientInstanceName="cbpStatus" OnCallback="cbpStatus_Callback">
                            <PanelCollection>
                                <dx:PanelContent>
                                    <table style="border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: separate; width: 600px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblInstructions" runat="server" Wrap="True" Text=""></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="display: none;">
                                            <td style="width: 90px;">Status:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbStatus" ClientInstanceName="cmbStatus" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" Width="160px">
                                                </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 90px;">Choose Status from Dropdown:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cboHeader" ClientInstanceName="cboHeader" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" Width="100%">
                                                    <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) {
                                                        cboReason.PerformCallback('');
                                                    }" />
                                                </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>OPTIONAL Choose Clarification:
```

Comment: what do you mean by "fold in" the new text?

Comment: that is, to show this text rather than the substitution instructions from the table.